# Multiple arrays in loop structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I cannot think of a way to loop through two arrays at the same time. This code is for outputting a function's data to different divs on a page. `array1` defines the input and `array2` defines the output.

How can I loop through the two arrays so that `item1` will always be paired with `'#div1'`, `item2` with `'#div2'`, etc.

```
var array1=[item1 , item2, item3, item4];
var array2=['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4'];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

    //code for to populate data goes here

    item.appendTo($(array2[i]));
};
```

Am I at least correct in wrapping my function in a for loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Since both arrays are of the same length and in the correct order, you can use the loop variable `i` to access both arrays, `array1[i]` and `array2[i]`.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `for (var i = 0; i<3; i++) {` It is outputting everything to the last item in the first array.

Comment: No, you can keep `for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {`, you don't have to change anything. You just have to use `i` to access `array1` like you do with `array2`. I think you are over-thinking this. There is really nothing extraordinary to do in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array1=[item1 , item2, item3, item4];
var array2=['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4'];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

    //code for to populate data goes here

    $(array1[i]).appendTo(array2[i]);

};
```

Comment: The `item` in this section `item.appendTo($(array2[i]));` is part of the function, so I am trying to append the `item` to the div in `array2`

Comment: Instead of using appendTo(), the same effect would be achieved using append() this way:         $(array2[i]).append(array1[i]);

Comment: I guess I am still not understanding since I would like to output `item` to a div stored in the array.

Comment: If `itemX` contains plain text, then this won't work. You cannot pass plain text to jQuery. You have to use the earlier version then, with `.append`.

Comment: @user2062244: I don't understand where your problem is. `array2[i]` is a string containing a selector and `array1[i]` is some data. You want to append the data to the element matched by the selector, hence you pass `array2[i]` to jQuery and pass `array1[i]` to `.append`. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bgE7Z/. What do you still not understand? You don't seem to accept any solution and keep explaining what you are trying to do instead. If the solutions don't work for you, you have to explain *why* and maybe provide a better explanation of your problem as well.

Comment: Sorry. You're right, I should've explained myself more clearly.. this is essentially what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/curly33/vRv7N/ I am trying to output data from different urls to different divs. Content from a url would be placed in a div according to its position in the array. I guess what I am having trouble with is outputting the scraped table data to a div in the second array. Line 23 is the output.

Comment: @user2062244: So I assumed you tried `output[i]` and didn't see anything? That's because you create closures (the success callbacks) inside the loop, and at the moment they are executed, the variable `i` has the value `3` (and `output[3]` is `undefined`). You have to capture the current value of `i` in each iteration. How this can be done is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196. The this is what you get: http://jsfiddle.net/vRv7N/1/.

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you so much. Thank you for the explanation link also. I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over two arrays at once. For security, just check if your index variable ('i') is not exceeding any of both arrays length.

Here's an example:

```
var array1=[item1 , item2, item3, item4];
var array2=['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4'];

var array3 = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < array1.length && i < array2.length; i++ ) {
    array3.push({
        el1: array1[i],
        el2: array2[i]
    });
}

for ( var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++ ) {
  // array3[i].el1; -- element from array1
  // array3[i].el2; -- element from array2
}
```

You can do this in one loop, of course. Here I've gone with two just for clarity (second one is logging only).

Comment: Unfortunately, this has to support IE8, so `Array.map` will not work.

Comment: You can chose not to use IE8, no problem. I'll update the answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Using the $() creates a jQuery object. You probably want to be creating the jQuery object off of the array2 values. When using a for loop the i variable will increment and you can use this to access the array members. Since you want the same index of both arrays using this for loop should work well

```
var array1=[item1 , item2, item3, item4];
var array2=['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4'];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    $(array2[i]).append(array1[i]); 
};
```

Comment: The `item` in this section `item.appendTo($(array2[i]));` is part of the function, so I am trying to append the `item` to the div in `array2`